# How to delete all the items in the dynamodb with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

My Code is below is to delete contents from the table name `details`

- The below code will delete some items according to `Capacity` of dynamodb which is working fine
- How to delete all the items

```
    import boto3
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        try:
            table_name = 'details'
            dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
            table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
            scan = table.scan()
            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for each in scan['Items']:
                    batch.delete_item(
                        Key={
                            'id': each['id']
                        }
                    )
        except Exception as e:
           print (e)
```

I wrote with `while` loop with a Flag condition.

```
   import boto3
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        try:
            flag = False
            table_name = 'details'
            dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
            table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
            scan = table.scan()
            while True:
                with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                    for each in scan['Items']:
                        if each is not None:
                            batch.delete_item(
                                 Key={
                                 'id': each['id']
                                 }
                             )
                         else:
                            Flag = True
        except Exception as e:
           print (e)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Where do you break out of the while loop in the second code example? I also expect you'll need to submit the batch too, but I don't know this interface.

Comment: Your are likely much better off deleting the table and re-creating it if you workflow allows - especially with bigger tables.

Comment: @balderman  how to delete all the items in the dynamo db table, please check the second code . what is the issue in the second code

Comment: @E.J.Brennan  I dont have permission, can you check the second code and what is the wrong in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DynamoDB if you want to delete all the items the best way it's to delete and recreate the table, because with boto3 you have a limit of 1000 elements per page.

The problem with do this with boto3 is the expensive cost... every delete it's a write request. If you don't want pay unnecessarily (and is the best way) delete and recreate :)

By the way...

```
import boto3
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        try:
            flag = False
            table_name = 'details'
            dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
            table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
            scan = table.scan()
            while !flag:
                with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                    for each in scan['Items']:
                        batch.delete_item(
                                 Key={
                                 'id': each['id']
                                 }
                             )
                    flag = True
        except Exception as e:
           print (e)
```

Comment: can you check the second code of me and help me in find the wrong in the code? I dont have persmision to delete the table

Comment: Ýour while never stop... while True: --> while flag:

and you need to determinate when flag is false... when you finish the foreach

Comment: but I insist if you need to delete all the items please delete and recreate... you pay unnecessarily... or create a terraform template to create and delete, it's the best standard

Comment: I'm edited my answer I think that solve your problem... but read my other comments

Comment: This code is clearly wrong and the author doesn't understand what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't edit the accepted answer due to the edit queue being full.

Looking at the code, it only scans and deletes items once.

Here's a working code by using the `LastEvaluatedKey` key to determine whether a rescan is necessary. The key exists when the scan reaches [the maximum dataset size limit of 1 MB](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan).

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     try:
          table_name = 'details'
          dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
          table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

          flag = True
          while flag:
               scan = table.scan()
               print(f"Deleting {scan['ScannedCount']} records...")
               flag = 'LastEvaluatedKey' in scan and scan['LastEvaluatedKey']
               with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                    for each in scan['Items']:
                         batch.delete_item(
                              Key={
                                   'id': each['id']
                              }
                         )
     except Exception as e:
          print(e)
```